# onClick set state for parent of parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm new to React and still learning, managing onClick from the parent element is easy but I'm not sure how I can then send that click up one or more steps to the parents of the parent. In my setup the components are like this Page > Header > Menu Button. The Header comp controls the menu opening and closing but for my animation purposes I need to set a state in the Page parent so it can pass it on to other components that are siblings of Header. When Menu Button is clicked I need to send it up the chain all the way to Page. Can someone please explain how this is achieved? Most examples I found just talk about a direct parent child onClick handle which I'm already doing with Header and Menu Button components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following example...

Use a click handler that has been passed down through the react component inheritance chain.

```
function MenuButton(props) {
    return <button onClick={props.onClick}>Do Something</button>
}

function Header(props) {
    return (
        <div>
        <MenuButton onClick={props.onClick} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Establish a click handler in the parent most component and pass as a prop to the child component like so...

```
class Page extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            someStateToCache: false
        };
        this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this); //bind context to click handler
    }

    clickHandler() {
        this.setState({ someStateToCache: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header onClick={this.clickHandler} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: found my answer on Facebook docs under "Lifting State Up" but your explanation is even simpler, so  thank you!

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: awesome, happy coding =]